# How to handle multiple notifications model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build website which monitor multiple websites for changes. For example - if keyword [XYZ] occurs on website A then send notification to user. Currently I'm stuck on adding more notification channels without creating mess in my code.

I want to create a abstract class with args `target`, `message`, methods like `send_message` and then inherence from it to `SMSNotification`, `PusherNotification`, `EmailNotification`.

Where should I put that logic into project? I was thinking about adding it to `models.py`, but I'm not sure if this won't cause troubles during further development. What's the proper approach for this?

Comment: is it your intent to save the notifications that you've sent in your database, or are they single use notifications which leave no trace?

Comment: I want to save them if for some reason the sending will fail. For example if there won't be sufficient funds on SMS Api provider. Otherwise I don't need to log them, as it will be simple, generic notification.

Comment: Ok, in that case models.py makes sense, do you have any code yet?

Comment: Currently only for email notifications into views.py. I will have to recode it to make code reusable. Thank you for your help, I'm glad the `models.py` approach made sense :-)

Comment: i can propose you a different approach if you want, using celery and rabbitMQ, when no funds on API, send you an email, and set a retry in 30mn (or do what you want). Its more scalable and more resistant

Comment: Thank you @MaximeK, I will look into it right now :-)